# hololens - using Azure Anchors with Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, hololens, azure-spatial-anchors

We are using Vuforia for image tracking with hololens and unity engine.  Vuforia works fine.  We are also using Azure Spacial Anchors to fix the location of objects.  However, Anchors do not seem to work with Vuforia.  It appears that Vuforia captures camera events and does not pass them on to Azure Anchors, maybe?

Is there a way to get both technologies working at the same time?

Comment: Can you detail what are the Unity Version, ARFoundation version, and ASA SDK version? When you mention "anchors do not seem to work" , do you get any error?

Answer (score 0):

the major issue would be Vuforia occupied the Camera pipeline
you may stop Vuforia and switch to ASA and switch back.

Or you may use pics and time stamps and ASA

Please read this page
https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/working-camera-unity
may help you get the camera frame. then you may make the parameter transferd to a service you hosted in linux server, with  Spatial https://github.com/microsoft/azure_spatial_anchors_ros